# Start animation of a control when content is added - xaml only

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation, prism

I have a content control in my application which is marked as a Prism region. When ever a module registres a view for this region, Prism sets the view as the content of the control.

That works fine, but now I would like to have an animation where the content is moved from top of the control into it, like the alerts in Internet Explorer. It is important that the animation is plain Xaml and no code behind because Prism does all the stuff in background and I don't want to touch it.

Now there is my problem: I tryed to follow the tutorial from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) but it does not work in my case because I would need to be able to trigger the animation when ever the content property of the element **is not** null while value trigger usually can only be triggered if the property has a specific value instead of having it not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [HasContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.hascontent.aspx) property of [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) - to see if it has content.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a DataTrigger and a converter to achieve what you want:

```
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Prop, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ConverterKey}}" Value="Value">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
```